# Get corresponding column value based on index in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have `df`:

```
            Id          Timestamp               Data    Id      Day
2012-04-21  19389576    2012-04-21 00:04:03.533 39.0    1       2012-04-21
2012-04-21  19389577    2012-04-21 00:04:04.870 38.5    1       2012-04-21
2012-04-21  19389608    2012-04-21 00:07:03.450 38.0    1       2012-04-21
2012-04-22  19389609    2012-04-21 00:03:04.817 37.5    2       2012-04-21
2012-04-22  19389620    2012-04-21 00:10:04.400 37.0    2       2012-04-21
                        ...
```

The first column of date is index. How can I get the corresponding `Id` value where `index == 2012-04-21`,  and `Data ==39`, which is `1`? I tried `iloc` and `loc` but I am not sure how to deal with indexes. Thanks.

Comment: There's a nice intro to how to select values from a data frame in the [documentation here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html#selection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try

```
df.loc[(df.index=='2012-04-21') & (df.Data==39) ,'Id']
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to return only the value of `1` rather than the entire row, since I was actually trying to print the result in a for-loop?